# Which operating systems ship with StartCom_Certification_Authority.pem

Tags: ssl, https, wordpress, certificate-authority

I purchased some (cheap) HTTPS certificates from StartSSL. They work great on all browsers I tested. According to [this post](http://www.startcom.org/?app=14&rel=33) they are even recognized in IE 7 and 8, which good enough for me.

However, one user complained that his WordPress RSS client/aggregator stopped working. His website runs the latest version of Wordpress and [simplepie](http://simplepie.org/), but it does not recognize the StartCom CA:

```
WP HTTP Error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I assume his wordpress site runs on some shared hosting service linux box. So now I'm curious, which versions of Debian, Ubuntu, RHEL, Fedora, FreeBSD, etc, include the StartCom root certificate?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem seems to be that you serve on www.opencpu.org the correct certificate for client which support SNI (Server Name Indication), e.g. which send the expected server name in the SSL handshake. But for clients which don't use SNI you send a certificate for dev1.opencpu.org, which neither matches the name nor it is signed by a trusted CA, but it is self-signed. But while current browser all support SNI some script libraries don't.

Because you provide a wildcard certificate for *.opencpu.org for clients using SNI I would recommend to just remove the dev1.opencpu.org certificate, because this hostname matches also the certificate *.opencpu.org.

To make also demo.ocpu.io work is harder. This name resolves to the same IP as the opencpu.org and thus clients which don't support SNI get the self-signed certificate for dev1.opencpu.org with the same problems, e.g. name mismatch and untrusted CA. If you need to support this hostname for client not supporting SNI you have to use a different IP address.

Comment: @Jeron: See https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=opencpu.org and https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=demo.ocpu.io for detailed report. You are sending the CA certificate, that's wrong. You should send only intermediate CA certificates. Also, you have anon and export suites enabled.

Answer (score 2):

This error can happen if you haven't already added the StartSSL intermediate CA certificate to your installation.  See the [StartSSL FAQ](https://www.startssl.com/?app=25#31) about that, or prepend (or append, I always forget which) the intermediate certificate to your server certificate within the certificate file.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem; I added the CA chain to my certificate and all browsers seem to understand it.

Comment: @Jeroen Can you verify that the intermediate is being sent?  Use `openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -showcerts`

Comment: The browsers cache intermediate CAs, so if another site using Startcom added the intermediate CA and you visited with your browser it will not fail, even if your server did not send the intermediate CA like required. In Firefox you realize the problem if you create a new profile and try to visit the site, because it does the caching per profile.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I'm not sure what to look at. My domains include `www.opencpu.org` and `demo.ocpu.io`